# OpenCV function pointPolygonTest() does not act like what I thought

Tags: c++, opencv

Please check my code, it does not work well. There is no errors occur during both build and debug session. I want to mark all the pixels with WHITE inside every contour. The contours are correct because I have drawn them separately. But the ultimate result is not right.

```
//Draw the Sketeches
    Mat sketches(detected.size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
    for (int j = ptop; j <= pbottom; ++j) {
        for (int i = pleft; i <= pright; ++i) {
            if (pointPolygonTest(contours[firstc], Point(j, i), false) >= 0) {
                sketches.at<uchar> (i, j)= 255;
            }
            if (pointPolygonTest(contours[secondc], Point(j, i), false) >= 0) {
                sketches.at<uchar> (i, j)= 255;
            }
        }
    }
```

The variable "Mat detected" is another image used for hand detection. I have extracted two contours from it as contours[firstc] and contours[secondc]. And I also narrow down the hand part in the image to row(ptop:pbottom), and col(pleft,pright), and the two "for" loop goes correctly as well. So where exactly is the problem?.
[Here is my result! Something goes wrong with it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39HT7.png)

[image]

Comment: can't you just draw the filled contours? `drawContours(sketches, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED)` ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix up ptop/pleft/pbottom?